# Poincaré Recurrence Theorem for flows

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Someone knows a book that have the proof of the Poincaré Recurrence Theorem for flows when the set have finite volume and when don't?

Comment: Apart from the initial papers of Poincare and the subsequent version of the proof by Caratheodory (you can find these references for example in: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_return_theorem), i think you can find a proof for the ergodic "version" of the theorem at: P. Walters, An introduction to ergodic theory, Graduate Texts in Mathematics, Vol. 79. 1982.